# PHP laravel echo html blade tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

am try to echo blade html tag but it error.

help me for check my code please

```
echo "<td><a href="{{ URL::to('index/watch/$tmpd') }}">$tmpd</a></td>";
```

variable tmpd is value for my loop

### From comments

Trying to echo this from within a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($words as $row) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    $tmpd = $row['title'];
    echo "<td><a href='watch/$tmpd'>$tmpd</a></td>";
}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Try like this: <td><a href="{{ URL::to('index/watch/$tmpd') }}">{{ $tmpd }}</a></td>

Comment: not work but i use <td><a href="{{ URL::to('index/watch/' . $tmpd) }}">{{ $tmpd }}</a></td> it work

Comment: sinle quote will not be interpreted

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a view file try

```
<td><a href="{{ URL::to('index/watch/' . $tmpd) }}">{{ $tmpd }}</a></td>
```

From the comments you are within a `foreach` loop. Using blade this should be something like:

```
@foreach($words as $row)
    <tr>{{ $row['title] }}
        <td><a href="{{ url('watch/' . $tmpd) }}">{{ $tmpd }}</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

With blade syntax like this you can remove this syntax from within any `<?php ?>` php tags you have.

My suggestion would be to look at the [blade syntax documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade).

Comment: not work yntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: tmpd is my variable it look like string i want to add to url

Comment: if i change to
echo "<td><a href='watch/$tmpd'>$tmpd</a></td>"; it work but

Comment: foreach ($words as $row) {
 echo '<tr>';
 $tmpd = $row['title'];
 echo "<td><a href='watch/$tmpd'>$tmpd</a></td>";

Comment: i want to use herf with blade

Comment: yes i know but your code say syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables inline when using apostrophes, e.g. 'Href: $href' will not work. You have to use quotes for that or add a variable separately.

Also, blade has foreach loop, which will make your templates more readable. Try this:

```
@foreach($words as $row)
    <tr><td><a href="{{ url('watch/' . $row['title']) }}">{{ $row['title'] }}</a></td>
@endforeach
```

If you are still getting errors, check other code in the same template - maybe you forgot to close a statement somewhere or something.

Comment: i try to use 
 echo "<td><a href="{{ url('watch/' . $row['title']) }}">{{ $row['title'] }}</a></td>";

but syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'